# Where do the two GATE animated series arrive with respect to the novel and the manga?

Tags: gate

I know that GATE: thus the JSDF fought here is a novel which has been then adapted into both a manga and two anime series. Since I am currently reading the manga I was wondering where I was with respect to the anime version and the novel.

I have reached the point where they fight the fire dragon, and I would like to avoid spoiling myself by watching the last episode of the season is currently being aired.

So, which chapters of the manga/volumes of the novel were adapted by the first season and which by the second?

Comment: The chapters adapted (at least from the novel) aren't all sequential. Theres a lot skipped. Are you trying to figure out what episode to start on?

Comment: I didn't know they weren't sequential, I expected that some subplots may have appeared earlier or later in the different adaptations, is it that drastic? To put it plainly, yes, I'm trying to understand where I should start if I wanted to watch the anime.

Comment: Well it's just a lot is skipped. >.< sorry don't want to confuse you.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, as for where things line up. As was mentioned in the comments, the Manga skips over things that were in the books and pulls in side stories from later books...and the anime skips over things that were in the manga. But here are a few 'line-up' points. I'm going to leave out exact details of what happens in those respective points so as not to spoil anything, but you should be able to put things together from there.

As it stands, the anime is actually further along in the story than the manga...so as of posting this, if you don't want to spoil the manga, stop watching at Episode 18 (Season 2, Episode 6). So, here are where things line up.

Book 1 -- Anime Episodes 1-10 -- Manga Chapters 1-24

Book 2 -- Anime Episodes 11-17 -- Manga Chapters 25-46(ish)

Book 3 -- Anime Episodes 18-current (should end at Ep 24) -- Manga Chapters 47-Current

There are a total of 10 books out there. Books 1-5 are the "Main Story" and books 6-9 are side stories focusing on a single one of the girls that surround Itami. Book 6 focuses on Pina, 7 on Rory, 8 on Tuka, and 9 on Lelei. Books 1 through 9 occur in chronological order. Book 10 is a collection of side stories that occur at differing points throughout books 1-9. Book 10 included the story that occurs in the manga but not in the anime where...

> Lelei falls ill on the way to Rondel; and Yao, Itami, and Rory end up battling undead and a minotaur to get the cure for her

Book 9 is intended to segue into a 'Season 2' series of books (not yet released) that will return the focus back to Itami to progress the main story.

Assuming you are talking about the true battle with the Fire Dragon...you are presently at the equivalent of Episode 17 (S2, ep5).